# find the occourance of pseudo-elements ::before or ::after beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i know that beautifulsoup could not parse pseudo-elements inside a HTML but is there a way to identify when it occours?

**My HTML code:** [HTML FILE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/125SZWMqJEcwY9NUL5FvOHFl-20sivnec/view?usp=sharing)

When is open this in a browser, i could see the occourence of ::before in the para tags that i need, but i couldn't see them in a text editor or when parsing in bs4.

**sample screenshot:**
[image: screenshot]

is there a way to find the occurance? like

```
if para.find("::before"):
*do sonething*
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

beautifulsoup is an HTML/XML parser

It does not generate a DOM API. It does not apply CSS.

Since it doesn't apply CSS, it can't know about psuedo-elements.

---

You could write/find a CSS parser, search it for `::before` selectors, then try to match the rest of the selector to an element using beautifulsoup.

It would probably be easier to use a different tool (one built around a headless browser).